# Olympics medal table by country revoked for cheating

Tags: history, olympics, awards

It is normal for Olympic competitions to have a *medal table*: a list of the countries in the order of golds, silvers, then bronzes.

Does such a *table by country* exist for medals which were won and then revoked for violation of rules in the Olympic Games?

Comment: Hi, Ale. Does cheating include taking banned substances?

Comment: @Rathony yes, off course. I think this is the reason of most retired medals

Comment: @rathony nowhere does the new revision say or suggest *only* use of banned substances is considered cheating for the purpose of the question.

Comment: Yes, cheating includes the use of banned substances. That **does not** imply all cheating is the use of banned substances. I strongly suggest you look up the definitions of inclusion and equality.

Answer (score 3):

It's not been answered for some time but now there is a complete List of stripped Olympic medals in this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stripped_Olympic_medals).

Part of a table:
[image: Piece of complete table]